# Showing that the sequence $\{f'_{n}(x)\}$ converges pointwise but not uniformly on $(-1,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Consider the sequence $\{f_{n} \}$ where for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the function $f_{n}\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by:
>       $$f_{n}(x)= \begin{cases}
> \lvert x \rvert & \text{if    } \frac{1}{n} \leq \lvert x \rvert \leq 1 \\
> \frac{n}{2}x^{2}+\frac{1}{2n} & \text{if    $ \lvert x \rvert \leq \frac{1}{n}$}
> \end{cases}$$
>   I want to show that the sequence $\{f'_{n}(x)\}$ converges pointwise  but not uniformly on $(-1,1)$.

For starters, I think

$$f'_{n}(x)= \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if    } \frac{1}{n} \leq x \leq 1 \\
nx & \text{if    $ \lvert x \rvert \leq \frac{1}{n}$} \\
-1 & \text{if    } -1 \leq x \leq \frac{-1}{n} \\
\end{cases}$$

So I think this implies that this sequence of functions converges to a discontinuous function (the piecewise function which is $-1$ on $[1,0)$ and $1$ on $(0,1]$. This should imply that the convergence is not uniform because otherwise the limit function would be continuous.

Is this reasoning okay? If not or more generally is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your reasoning is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost entirely correct. You just forgot to add that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n'(0)=0$. So, yes, $(f_n')_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges pointwise to a non-continuous functions and, since each $f_n'$ is continuous, the convergence cannot be uniform.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was having trouble with.

Comment: @user135520 I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.

To be entirely precise, $(f_n')_n$ converges to the function $\operatorname{sgn} : [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$\operatorname{sgn} x  = \begin{cases}
-1,  & \text{if $x < 0$} \\
0,  & \text{if $x = 0$} \\
1, & \text{if $x > 0$}
\end{cases}$$
which is not continuous at $0$.

You can also notice that

$$\left|\operatorname{sgn}\left(\frac1{2n}\right) - f_n'\left(\frac1{2n}\right)\right| = 1 - \frac12 = \frac12, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

which shows that the convergence is not uniform.